# Laravel 5.1 eloquent relations

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I was implementing a quiz system using Laravel 5.1

I was facing some problems with inserting and updation of data in questions table

MySQL Schema

```
Subjects  (Table 1)
________________
Subject_ID (Primary Key) auto_increment,
Subject_Name


Questions (Table 2)
________________
Question_ID (Primary Key) auto_increment,
Question,
Options_1,
Options_2,
Options_3,
Options_4,
Answer,
Subject_Id (Foreign Key refers to Primary Key of Subjects Table [Table 1])
```

While inserting question in the questions table, I was unable to get the Subject_Id from Subjects table

I was implementing the following query using Laravel

```
insert into questions values("", "Question", "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Answer", "select subject_id from subjects where subject_name = $subject_name");
```

$subject_name is the variable that fetches the subject name from the user interface

Answer (score 0):

You can create this two tables with migrations files.

First write command in command line

```
php artisan make:migration Subjects
```

So create migration file and for second table

```
php artisan make:migration Questions
```

After that go in your app directory/database/migrations and there you will found this 2 migration files.
In first file "Subjects" in method up() you need to have this code

```
Schema::create('Subjects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('Subject_ID');
        $table->string('Subject_Name',255);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

In second file "Questions" in method up() you need to have this code

```
Schema::create('Questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('Question_ID');
        $table->string('Question',255);
        $table->string('Options_1',255);
        $table->string('Options_2',255);
        $table->string('Options_3',255);
        $table->string('Options_4',255);
        $table->string('Answer',255);
        $table->integer('Subject_Id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('Subject_Id')->references('Subject_ID')->on('Subjects');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

After all files is on the server go again to command line and write

```
php artisan migrate
```

I hope that i help you. Write comment if i am not understand you and if this is not that you want to do.